# Replace every instance of a string except the last one

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a string structured in the following way

```
XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest
```

I'd like to change every `XX` up to the last one before every `\n` character to `YY`, so the following

```
$ echo "XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest"
XXthisXXisXXjust
XXa
XXtest
```

should become

```
$ echo "XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest" | ???
YYthisYYisXXjust
XXa
XXtest
```

how can I do this?

EDIT: I think my original question is a bit of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I apologize for it. In my case I need to modify color codes, so `XX` is actually the bold blue color code `[1;34m`, and `YY` is the bold grey color code `[1;90m`.

Btw, I could have more than 3 instances of `[1;34m` on the same line (including the last line).

Again, I apologize if I wasted your time, I thought the solution would generalize easily to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ printf 'XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest\n' | sed 's/XX/YY/g; s/\(.*\)YY/\1XX/'
YYthisYYisXXjust
XXa
XXtest
```

The `sed` code annotated:

```
s/XX/YY/g;              # change all XX to YY
s/\(.*\)YY/\1XX/;       # replace last YY with XX
```

That second substitution will replace the last `YY` in the modified line with `XX` since `.*` is greedy.

If your `XX` is `[1;34m` and `YY` is `[1;90m`, then

```
sed 's/\[1;34m/[1;90m/g; s/\(.*\)\[1;90m/\1[1;34m/'
```

Note that `[` has to be escaped as `\[` if you want to match it in a regular expression.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If YY happens to be present and after the last XX then the greedy regex captures wrong data. You need \n marker.

Comment: @RakeshSharma In that case you could first change all `XX` to some unique `ZZ`, then change the last `ZZ` to `XX`, in the same manner as before.  Then  change the remaining `ZZ` to `YY`. It's an extra step and requires that one can come up with an `ZZ` that works.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` and `rev`:

```
$ echo "XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest" | rev | sed 's/XX/YY/2g' | rev
YYthisYYisYYjust\nYYa\nXXtest

$ echo -e "XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest" | rev | sed 's/XX/YY/2g' | rev
YYthisYYisXXjust
XXa
XXtest
```

No need to reverse the search and replace strings, i.e. `XX` and `YY` in this particular case as they are palindromic.

Comment: True, but works for the specific string specified by the OP.  Not intended to be a GP solution.

Comment: Since you are reversing the data so you need to reverse the regex as well. Although in this case XX is palindromic so won't matter.

Comment: @RakeshSharma. Of course, that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

1. I first change all the instances of `XX` and replace them with `YY`.

`s/XX/YY/g`

2. I then replace anything that begin with `\nYY` with `\nXX`

`s/\\nYY/\nXX/g`

3. I finally replaced the 3rd occurrence of `YY` to `XX`

`s/YY/XX/3`

```
[root@ServerA studyroom]# echo "XXthisXXisXXjust\nXXa\nXXtest" | sed 's/XX/YY/g;s/\\nYY/\nXX/g;s/YY/XX/3'
YYthisYYisXXjust
XXa
XXtest
```

As one of my colleagues would say, all roads lead to Rome, some faster than others.